# Pyautogui clicks but it wont move the mouse

Tags: python, pyautogui

Pyautogui wont move the mouse but it will click just fine. I have tried adding the Terminal & python to permissions for taking over the computer, I have tried the drag options and setting coordinates manual. Nothing seems to work, its very frustrating. I'm on a new apple m1 chip, I doubt that is doing it but I thought I would mention it. Any help would be awesome!

```
def traffic(self):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    traffic = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('./Traffic.png', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.moveTo(traffic, duration=1)
    time.sleep(0.8)
    pyautogui.click(clicks=2, interval=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not move is because `Traffic.png` is not found, which returns None, which makes the mouse not move anywhere. To make sure the computer finds it, do a little `print(traffic)` after the `locateOnScreen()`. To increase the likelihood of finding the image, try setting it to grayscale and lowering the confidence value.

Comment: Hey Laggy Tablet, I thought that too, but I set the value manually and it still isn't moving with the coordinates. Also it wasn't kicking back any kind of error for the image. So i'm very confused.

Comment: So after further testing I think your right Laggy Tablet. I did a if loop and it keeps printing none. I also tried the grayscale and confidence and nothing. So I am really confused. I read online that people took a screenshot of the whole image and just cropped out the part they needed so maybe i'll try that next and update how it goes.

Comment: yeah, I figured, good luck trying to make it work

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you, all you need to do is run python as administrator, like this comment if you find it helpful

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32797975)